# About developing Add-on for Firefox

Tags: firefox

I would like to define different actions for different pages

I would like to do like this, when I entry :

wwww.test.com/page1.html : alert Hello!

wwww.test.com/page2.html : alert Good morning!

wwww.test.com/page3.html : alert Hi!

How do I implement this idea

Any tutorial links? thinks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are three general types of Firefox add-ons: [Overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions), [Restartles (Bootstraped)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions), and using the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) (Software Development Kit). There is a good article [comparing the three types on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Comparing_Extension_Toolchains) (Mozilla Developer Network).

In general, the most flexible are Overlay extensions. Bootstrapped (Restartless) extensions sacrifice some of the capabilities available to overlay extensions for the ability to install and uninstall without requiring the user to restart Firefox. Add-on SDK extensions sacrifice a considerable amount of the capabilities available to the other two types of extensions for having an abstraction layer between the extension writer and the guts of Firefox. The Add-on SDK is intended to make writing extensions easier and reduce the amount of work needed by the person writing the extension to maintain compatibility with future versions of Firefox. It mostly succeeds at this, but it does fail in some ways.

There are tutorials available on MDN:

- [Getting Started with Firefox Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Getting_Started_with_Firefox_Extensions)
- [XUL School Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School)
- [Building an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension)
- [Add-on SDK Tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials#getting-started) (many)
- Many more

MDN is a good resource for information about extensions.  When working on Firefox extensions I typically have *at least* one tab open to a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&lr=&as_qdr=all&q=MDN%20Add-on%20SDK%20tutorial&oq=MDN%20Add-on%20SDK%20tutorial&gs_l=serp.3...206459.211922.0.212294.25.19.1.0.0.5.767.3312.2-2j3j2j0j1.8.0....0...1c.1.53.serp..25.0.0.0WMbh-mg4dg) for "MDN " and then whatever I am looking for. It is my go-to method of finding documentation for developing Firefox extensions.

There are a couple of forums which have good information:

- [Mozilla Add-on Forum](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/index.php?sid=9e476768678b3f359b11522958a8d71a) (Official)
- [mozillaZine](http://www.mozillazine.org/)

Welcome to developing extensions for Firefox.

As to the specific question you asked, the exact code depends on if you are using the Add-on SDK, or not.  For the SDK, you should read [Working with Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Working_with_Events) and [Listen for Page Load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listen_for_Page_Load) among others.  For the other types: [Intercepting Page Loads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads),  [Listening to events in Firefox extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Listening_to_events_in_Firefox_extensions), and [On page load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load) (Code snippet); also among others.